# Recursion Depth Exceeded - Python Doubly-Linked List

Tags: python, fifo, doubly-linked-list

I'm in the process of creating a FIFO implemented as a doubly-linked list, but I'm at a loss as to why I'm receiving a recursion error.  I've posted my code and the error I received below.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
"""DLList.py"""

class DLList(object):
    """A doubly-linked list

    attributes: nl = node list"""
    def __init__(self, nl=[]):
        self.nl = nl

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nl)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.nl)

    def append(self, node):
        if not isinstance(node, DLNode):
            raise TypeError
        try:
            node.pn = self.nl[-1]
            node.pn.nn = node
            self.nl.append(node)
        except:
            self.nl.append(node)

    def pop(self):
        rn = self.nl.pop(0)
        try:
            self.nl[0].pn = None
        except:
            pass
        return rn


class DLNode(object):
    """A node in a doubly-linked list.

    attributes: self.pn = previous node, self.data = data, self.nn = next node"""
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.pn = None
        self.data = data
        self.nn = None

    def __str__(self):
        return '[%s, %s, %s]' % (self.pn, self.data, self.nn)


a = DLNode(17)
b = DLNode(15)
c = DLNode(12)
d = DLNode(46)
e = DLNode(46)

ages = DLList()
ages.append(a)
ages.append(b)
ages.append(c)
ages.append(d)
ages.append(e)

print ages.pop()
```

I received this error:

```
File "C:\python\swampy-2.0\DLList.py", line 43, in __str__
    return '[%s, %s, %s]' % (self.pn, self.data, self.nn)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The thing is, I never intended to use recursion, and I can't figure out why I've entered into a recursive loop.  ages.pop() is meant to return an instance of DLNode.

Comment: One thing, don't use `[]` as your default argument.  Every instance of `DLList` will reference the same `list` instance in this case.  Use `None` and then check for `None` and generate a new `list` object on the fly in `__init__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you print the node, you are trying to print self.pn and self.nn.  Each of those is a reference to another node, which when printed will try to print its next node and previous node, and so on, ad infinitum.  You are asking to print an infinite hall of mirrors of nodes.

You have nothing keeping track of what has already been printed, so the recursion will continue forever.

Comment: In theory though this would stop when `.pn` or `.nn` is `None` as specified in the `DLNode`'s `__init__()`.

Comment: @Toomai: the links go both ways.  In a two-element list, the first element will try to print the second element, which in turn will try to print the first, and so on.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't the best way to print this anyway.  Printing any element will print every element since `pn` and `nn` are both node objects with their own `__str__()`.  Probably should do `(id(self.pn), self.value, id(self.nn))` in your `DLNode.__str__()` instead.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for the incredibly fast response!  I'll take out the reference to self.pn and self.nn from the str representation.

Comment: You might also want to alter `DLList.__str__()` to do something like return a string with the id and value of each node in the list.  Having it just print each element with it's own `__str__()` as it does know seems a little redundantly verbose.  But that's style.

Comment: @sr2222, I was unfamiliar with the .id attribute until you brought it up.  Thanks for the tip.  Is that an attribute that any class that inherits from object will have built in?

Comment: Well, my syntax was wrong.  ;)  I fixed my comment.  `id()` will get you the internal id of any entity; you can think of it like a memory address for the most part.  If memory serves, when you do an `is` comparison on 2 objects, it is checking to see if they have the same id.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I recommend using `collections.deque` instead? You can read its documentation in the [library](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.deque). Unless you are writing your implementation as an academic exercise, `deque` is probably better.

Comment: It was entirely an academic exercise, intended to introduce the deque framework in python.  Thanks for the recommendation, however.